# AudioTrack static mode implementation

Tags: android

I am trying to learn how to implement an audiotrack class, the simplest way possible. I have researched many topics but I still did not understand the audiotrack.
I made a simple application that consists of only one button, which when pressed executes a 1 sec `*.wav` file. 
but when I press the button the app crashes.
Can someone help me?

Below my java code, and LogCat:

**MainActivity.java :**

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    private DrumKit dk = new DrumKit();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
        }  

    public void onClick(View v) { 
        dk.playAudio();
    } 
   }
```

**Class to run the audio:**

```
     public class DrumKit {

     byte[] byteData = null;
     private File file = null; 
     private AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100,
            AudioFormat. CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 88200,
            AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC );

     public void playAudio(){

         file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "snare.wav");
         byteData = new byte[(int) file.length()];

         audioTrack.play();
         audioTrack.write(byteData, 0, byteData.length); 
         audioTrack.stop();
         audioTrack.release();
     }
  }
```

**Logcat:**

```
06-05 10:23:01.131: D/gralloc_goldfish(1381): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-05 10:23:14.371: D/AndroidRuntime(1381): Shutting down VM
06-05 10:23:14.371: W/dalvikvm(1381): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a1eba8)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381): Process: com.example.airdrums, PID: 1381
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at     android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     ... 11 more
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: play() called on uninitialized AudioTrack.
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.media.AudioTrack.play(AudioTrack.java:984)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at com.example.airdrums.DrumKit.playAudio(DrumKit.java:25)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at com.example.airdrums.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:51)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the audio track before playing it.  Otherwise there's no data to play.

In addition, your code doesn't actually read in the file, so you're trying to play random bytes.